# Docker: MacOSX Expose Container ports to host machine

Tags: macos, docker, ports

In my job I working with docker and the option `--net=host` working like a charm forwarding the docker container ports to the machine. This allows me to adding grunt tasks that use certain ports by example:

- A taks for serving my coverage report in a port 9001
- A local deployed version of my app served in the port 9000
- A watch live reload the port 35729
- For Unit testing runner use the 9876 port

When I begin to use Docker in Mac, the first problem that i had was: The option `--net=host` don't work anymore. 
I researched and I understand why this is not possible (Docker in Mac runs in a own virtual machine) and my momentary solution it's use the `-p` option for expose the ports, but this limit to me to add more and more task that use ports because i need run the explicit `-p` command for each port that i need expose.

**Anyone with this same problem? How to dealing with this ?**

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your issue is most probably that you are using dockertoolbox or dhingy/dlite or anything else providing a **full-fledged linux VM**, which then hosts docker to run your container inside this VM. This VM has, of course, its own network stack and own IP on the host, and thats were your tools will have issues with. The exposed ports of the container are not exposed to `OSX host localhost`, but rather `OSX Docker-VM-ip`.

To solve those issues elegantly

### Expose ports to OSX `localhost` from the container

1. First, use/install docker-for-mac https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/mac/ instead of dockertoolbox or others. Its based on a special xhyve stack which reuses your hosts network stack
2. when you now do `docker run -p 3306:3306 percona` it will bind 3306 on the `osx-host-localhost`, thus every other osx-tool trying to attach to localhost:3306 will work ( very useful ) just as you have been used to it when you installed mysql using `brew install mysql` or likewise
3. If you experience performance issues with code shares on OSX with docker containers, check http://docker-sync.io - it is compatible with docker-for-mac ( hint: i am biased on this one )

---

### Export ports from the OSX-host to a containter

You do not really export anything in particular, you rather make them accessable as a whole from all containers ( all ports of the OSX-host-localhost)

If you want to **attach** to a port you offered on the OSX host, **from within a container**, e.g. during a xdebug session were your IDE listens on port 9000 **on the OSX-host-localhost** and the container running FPM/PHP should **attach** to this osx-localhost:9000 on the mac, you need to do this: https://gist.github.com/EugenMayer/3019516e5a3b3a01b6eac88190327e7c

So you create a dummy loopback ip, so you can access your OSX-host ports from without containers using 10.254.254.254:9000 - this is portable and basically gives you all you need to develop like you have used to

---

So one gives you the connectivity to container-exposed ports to apps running on the mac and trying to connect to localhost:port

And the second the inverse, if something in the container wants to attach to a port on the host.

Answer (score 1):

One workaround, mentioned in "[Bind container ports to the host](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/binding/)" would be to use `-P`:

> (or `--publish-all=true|false`) to [`docker run`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#/network-container) which is a blanket operation that identifies every port with an `EXPOSE` line in the image’s Dockerfile or `--expose <port>` commandline flag and maps it to a host port somewhere within an ephemeral port range.
>   The **[`docker port`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/port/)** command then needs to be used to inspect created mapping.

So if your app can use `docker port <CONTAINER>` to retrieve the mapped port, you can add as many containers as you want and get the mapped ports that way (without needed an "explicit `-p` command for each port").

Comment: The question states that -P option does not work on MacOS

Comment: @user7865286 True. Maybe is has changed since 2016?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if docker for mac can support bi-directional connection later https://forums.docker.com/t/will-docker-for-mac-support-bi-directional-connection-between-host-and-container-in-the-future/19871

I have two solution:

1. you can write a simple wrapper script and pass the port you want to expose to the script
2. use vagrant to start a virtual machine with network under control.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue, but couldn't find an answer in any of the relevant threads. The following worked for me.

Recapping the scenario:

- There is a service on the MacOS host that is listening on port X.
- We want to run a container that will connect to that service.

#### Solution if your client can perform DNS resolutions

If your client can accept a hostname as input and perform DNS resolutions, the solution is as simple as replacing `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` in your target address with `host.docker.internal`.

Example: If you client tries to connect to the server using `localhost:8080`, just replace that with `host.docker.internal:8080`.

#### Solution if your client can't perform DNS resolutions

If your client cannot accept hostnames, and requires an IP address, you will have to help with the DNS resolution manually.

First, run the container interactively once, and use a DNS resolution tool (e.g. `nslookup`) to resolve the IP address of `host.docker.internal`. For example:

```
root@c05d907053e5:/app# nslookup host.docker.internal
Server:         127.0.0.11
Address:        127.0.0.11#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   host.docker.internal
Address: 192.168.65.2
```

Then, just replace the server address with the resolved address (`192.168.65.2` in this example).

Example: If you client tries to connect to the server using `127.0.0.1:8080`, just replace that with `192.168.65.2:8080`.

#### Notes:

- You don't need to pass any `--network` flags to `docker run`