# PyCharm remote debug in a docker container

Tags: python, docker, pycharm

I'm having an hard time trying to figure out how to setup a remote debug of a python app (Flask) running in a Docker container.
Specifically I'm using docker-compose, PyCharm professional and python 3.5.
This is what I've done so far:

- I copied "pycharm-debug-py3k.egg" into the project folder
- I added the following lines in the wsgi.py file:

  ```
  import sys
  sys.path.append('../pycharm-debug-py3k.egg') 
  import pydevd 
  pydevd.settrace('0.0.0.0', port=8200, stdoutToServer=True, stderrToServer=True)
  ```
- I created a remote debug configuration in PyCharm (by mapping the path of my local machine project path to the one in the docker container)

by running the debug configuration (click on the bug icon) from PyCharm it prints (and hangs):

```
Starting debug server at port 4200
Use the following code to connect to the debugger:
import pydevd
pydevd.settrace('0.0.0.0', port=4200, stdoutToServer=True, stderrToServer=True)
Waiting for process connection...
```

...and in the docker container logs I read:

> Could not connect to 0.0.0.0: 4200

What should I do? (My goal is to be able to add breakpoints in PyCharm and stop the execution of the docker container app in order to debug it)

Comment: We need more informations. Did you setup Python as remote SDK - if yes, you have an SSHD server on the container i suggest. In this cases, pycharm should actually do it all for you, regarding the tunnel - it will no longer be a docker question

Comment: Nope, I'm not using a remote interpreter... should I?

Comment: check your port number, looks like in your `wsgi.py` file you defined `pydevd.settrace('0.0.0.0', port=8200, stdoutToServer=True, stderrToServer=True)` but the debug server is running on `4200`, maybe changing to `pydevd.settrace('0.0.0.0', port=4200, ...` works?

Answer (score 13):

Use `host.docker.internal` instead of `0.0.0.0`. This will allow docker to decide which IP to use.

Comment: this should be the accepted answer. and yeah, @Pitt is also correct - ports should be the same, both in the running python remote debug server and in the injected code with the pydevd trace.

Answer (score 11):

Use a remote interpreter, this will solve a couple of issues at once. I already answered this here [Rich editors in a Docker development environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41314328/rich-editors-in-a-docker-development-environment/41317770#41317770)

Add a remote python SDK to your IDE, this will then also resolve all the libraries being installed remotely. You will require an SSH connection to get this done though, so install sshd and use the shared developer key I outlined in my answer.

Even though this now a bit more effort, I will give you a lot better results, also in the other sections you did not yet encounter and will find, when doing just a remote-port connection.

If you still want to use the port-based debugging, see [Docker: MacOSX Expose Container ports to host machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38733992/docker-macosx-expose-container-ports-to-host-machine/38985163#38985163) - this explains how you should understand the attach and the listen part.

Comment: So you are advocating injecting a sshd and setting up ssh access on every container we need to debug?

Comment: Since that is the the usual and right now only way to do that, yes. Sshd with a shared key for all devs, for the DEV images only of course. you will trade the Sshd extra effort against solving a bunch of issues at once.

Comment: After having spent the last 3 hours reading, I tend to agree. What about reverse tunnelling a port remote_host -> local_client, calling that port from the code executing in the container (settrace) using the remote_host bridge IP (with the remote debugger running setup on the IDE on local_client)(confusing, I know, that's why I tend to agree with you....)

Comment: I agree with what you wrote (also in the linked answer), but this doesn't really show how to do it. I have to find a bug inside an API written with Python/Django and tried to set up PyCharm Professional with the remote debugger, but I always got "socket closed" "connection to python debugger failed" and don't know how to resolve it. Can you please put some details into your answer (ideally step-by- step) so one is able to set it up correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should connect to you self host machine that is you pycharm in. not 0.0.0.0 instead of you self ip address